# What does the Mantaflow 'time' setting for noise do?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Does anyone know what the 'time' setting for noise is supposed to do?
I've made a sim, and I'm trying to make the noise move/develop/scintillate more slowly. Which I'd sort of assumed the 'time' control was for, but my findings would make it appear otherwise...

So here's the same sim, with multiple different 'time' settings for the noise:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNbeHS5C3xE&feature=youtu.be

It's a bit difficult to watch eight at once, so I knocked it back to four:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ghOibSh5vA&feature=youtu.be

I can't see much of a difference between them, I definitely can't see a 1000 times difference between 0.01 & 10!

Here's the smoke zoomed a bit:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9JsSyI-im8&feature=youtu.be

Still not seeing terribly much difference! Am I using the control wrong?
I mean the tool-tip says 'animation time of noise', which you'd think made the noise faster or slower, no?

I must admit I've only used Mantaflow for Gas sims so far, so this control may well be fantastic for 'wet' fluid sims, but does anyone know how to slow the noise down in a gas sim?

For that matter - does anyone have any docs for Mantaflow in general?!?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the time factor basically acts as a control for the coordinates of the noise. So it just changes the position and look of the noise, but not really related to time in the sense of how the noise behaves over time.

Answer (score -2):

Sort of had this answered on the BA forum: basically it's a bit of a grey area!!!
It's at the bottom of this post / thread (at the moment anyway!).

https://blenderartists.org/t/lets-talk-about-mantaflow/644346/675

Ta all!